# dotnet Core - File.Open(path) pre-pending application Root

Tags: c#, .net-core

Trying to open a pdf usinf File.Open(). Ive done this before but for some reason the application root is now being prepended to the path that i put in. Just upgraded to visual studio 17 so not sure if that is related.

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.Open(@"‪C:\Projects\xxxx\Forms\xxxxx.pdf",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {....}
```

For whatever reason it looks for C:\projects\xxxx\forms\xxxxx.pdf inside of the bin. I get a file does not exist (because it doesn't nor should it)

Comment: What do you mean 'inside of the bin'? What OS are you running it on? Why did you upgrade to an outdated Visual Studio?

Comment: Windows, ANd my mistake. It is visual studio 2019. And it is looking for my path inside of the bin. The `.....\bin\debug\netcoreapp2.2\C:\Projects\xxxx\Forms\xxxxx.pdf`

Comment: Not possible. Show the actual code that builds the path string. Or are you hosting on Linux?

Comment: Its definitely possible, its happening. Not hosting on linux.

Comment: its like you are sandboxed or something. i tested this code in a fresh console app and it opens up at file location i specify.

Comment: @LCaraway, are you sure this is the exact code you're using? I find it hard to believe, as well.

Comment: `System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect : 'C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\ConvertToFDF\ConvertToFDF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\‪C:\Projects\xxxx\Forms\xxxx.pdf''`

Comment: This is the exact code. Error gets thrown on the File.Open(...). I agree it is very strange

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you create a new project and attempt to do the same?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Can you try something just for debugging purposes? `var fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Projects\xxxx\Forms\", "xxxxx.pdf");` and then `File.Open(fileName)` instead and put a breakpoint to see what the value of fileName is.

Comment: This worked.. Why did this work....

Comment: What if you don't use `Path.Combine`? i.e. `var fileName = @"‪C:\Projects\xxxx\Forms\xxxxx.pdf"`?

Comment: Does not work without the Path.Combine()

Comment: Can you do a breakpoint and compare the values of the variable fileName with and without Path.Combine?

Comment: The one without the Path.Combine() adds a "?" at the beginning of the path. `‪?C:\Projects\xxxx\Forms\xxxxx.pdf`

Comment: I don't get it. What does Path.IsRooted(fileName); return on either version?

Comment: I do not get it either... The Path.Combine() returns true. The one without returns false.

Comment: I always separate folder from file name and use Path.Combine but I can't say I ever came across a prepended question mark. I'm stumped and can't help you further. Hopefully you feel closer to identifying the issue, however.